# How do I add additional plugins to my already existing CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

This link https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_example_setups strongly encourages use of the CKEditor builder in order to manage plugins, and strongly discourages installing plugins manually.

> ## Manual Download and Installation of Additional Plugins (Not Recommended)
>
> Although at a first glance it looks like the simplest way
> of adding plugins to CKEditor, it is not only inefficient but also may
> result in a headache when trying to add plugin A, that requires plugin
> B, that requires plugin C (...and so on).
>
> In a brief summary it involves the following steps:
>
> 1. Downloading the predefined package (Basic/Standard/Full) from the
>    Download page.
> 2. Downloading additional plugins manually from the
>    Add-ons Repository.
> 3. Downloading plugins required by additional plugins
>    manually.
> 4. Enabling additional plugins manually through
>    CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins.

Then it tauts its Builder:

> ## Using Builder (Recommended)
>
> Using Builder to build a bundle with all required plugins is highly recommended in case of using customized
> packages, especially those with additional third-party plugins.
>
> Refer to the Installing Plugins – Online Builder Installation article
> for information about building a custom editor package.

But in visiting the page for Builder, unless I'm missing something, it only builds a completely brand new CKEditor from scratch. I can't find any way to keep my current configuration and add plugins.

If there is literally no way to add existing plugins except by doing it manually, I find the language in the docs strongly discouraging this very strange (since 99.9% of the time I'll want to add plugins on the fly and not at the very beginning).

So is manually adding plugins the way to go if I already have other stuff set up?

Comment: If you try to find the file named composer.json or package.json inside this module they can save your installation and try to install by the hand as you wanted every requirement modules needed to be installed with CKEditor that the reason why they warn people who wanted to install manually this package. Regards

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. I don't see any package.json or composer.json files. I do see build-config.js. Is that related to this? Are you saying there is a way to keep track of your setup and whenever you add a new plugin you reinstall? How is this done exactly?

Comment: May be you got on this files the requirement "library needed" to a clean install, or readme can got this information. Regards

Comment: "So is manually adding plugins the way to go if I already have other stuff set up?" Yes it is if you know what you are doing. Sometimes plugins have dependencies (other plugins which needs to be installed) or new plugins which won't work with older version of the editor. If you can manage that, manual method is for you.

Comment: That's not complicated @j.swiderski...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most crucial point to keep up with builder is to keep your CKEditor up-to-date. Imaging pain of updating all plugins manually.

Just build our base CKEditor - with ckeditor itself and plugins which 100% you will use in your project.

But no one stops you from adding your own or community plugins. You just need to configure and keep `config.js` in your ckeditor folder. so you will have your extra plugin configured on each ckeditor update.